# What should we call the chatroom?

Tags: discussion, chat

We have [a chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/latin-language), which a number of users have already found. Along with that there came the suggestion that we could change the name - perhaps to Lorem Ispum.

However, I'm sure we can do better than that. Propose names here as answers - one name per answer - and the voting can show which we should use. I'll return to this thread next week sometime, pick the highest voted, and rename the chatroom.

Comment: Since this is a fairly visible decision and chat users aren't necessarily active on meta, do we have any way of making this a featured meta question?

Comment: Hmm I have seen some decent suggestion. But I'm looking for something with that extra spart, something with humour maybe, or a literary reference? Camera Obscura is...meh. Perhaps a variation on *Forum*? The something Forum?

Comment: As long as the letter v is used and u is not, I'm ok with any name the community should decide upon. :)

Comment: @Lilienthal Only moderators can add the [featured] tag. We have to wait for a community team member to notice this post. (It is listed as a "hot" meta post, though.)

Comment: @Earthliŋ I had flagged this for mod attention based on a discussion in chat but it seems like it wasn't picked up. Still, this question has gotten a fair bit of exposure and changing the chat's name later isn't a big deal so it's probably fine.

Comment: @Art So, given that this question has sat for a while, should we change the name now to the most upvoted answer? (i.e. CONLOQVIVM)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes all done.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## **Colloquium** sive **CONLOQVIVM** sive **COLLOQVIVM**

It's Latin and English, it has 'to talk together' right in the etymology, and it means exactly what we need it to mean. Plus it's not fake Latin.

Lewis and Short define it as "a conversation, conference, discourse" and note that it is used in both classical poetry and prose. Cicero also uses it to mean "epistolary correspondence", which is appropriate to our chat since it's all written.

Comment: With alternate spelling: Colloqvivm

Comment: @ArtofCode Perhaps in all caps? COLLOQVIVM, or the Classical CONLOQVIVM?

Comment: @C.M.Weimer: I support the capitals. // Was -LL- really not used in the classical age?

Answer (score 12):

## The Forum / The FORVM

*Alternative spelling added as [suggested](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/what-should-we-call-the-chatroom/30#comment137_30) by Ben Kovitz.*

It's both Latin and English. It's a short, single word that is easily referred to: "*please take it to the forum*" is a lot nicer to say than "*please discuss that in chat*" or "*please move the discussion to [Insert Latin Phrase Here]*"

It's also intuitive and perfectly encompasses what chatrooms are on StackExchange: an extension of the site for users to come together for the purpose of discussion.

As a bonus I like the historical tie to Ancient Rome which had the [most famous forum of all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Forum).

---

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forum#English):

> forum ‎(plural forums or fora)
>
> - A place for discussion.
> - A gathering for the purpose of discussion.
> - A form of discussion involving a panel of presenters and often participation by members of the audience.
> - (Internet) An Internet message board where users can post messages regarding one or more topics of discussion.

Comment: I don't know about this; though it is logical in Latin, it is likely to bring to mind a typical internet forum, which is somewhat different from chat.

Comment: I like the irony of this (and was going to suggest this myself): *Stack Exchange is not a forum, but our chatroom is …*

Comment: How about The FORVM?

Comment: @BenKovitz Added as an alternative.

Answer (score 5):

How about the *Conclave*? It's a good word in both Latin and English: not just the separate room, but in Lewis and Short (and perhaps more in the spirit of the chatroom) a dining hall or even animal coop...!

Answer (score 5):

**Locutorium**.

There are several other Latin sites that use that name to refer to their chatrooms.

That said, I don't have strong feelings on the matter!

Answer (score 2):

A bit trite, but: **Veni, Vidi, Dixi**

Comment: Hope I got that right... <crosses fingers>

Comment: Does it have to be English titlecase?

Comment: @chirlu Do you mean, *Veni, vidi, dixi*? Or, adding macrons?

Comment: Yes, I meant the capitalization (i.e. “Veni, vidi, dixi”).

Comment: @chirlu I'm fine with it either way, but it'd be a proper name, and so wouldn't titlecase be appropriate?  (Maybe not, I don't know Latin well enough to say.)

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I won't be offended if you post your own version of this, using *inquii* instead. I didn't figure *dixi* was the best choice, but I didn't know any better options.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer: I'm not sure *inquii* would be better? That is a very rare form. *Locutus sum* is probably more "normal", but...that doesn't sound good. While *dixi* probably doesn't mean "I chatted", it is not inconceivable for someone to come to chat to say something to the group, then leave, so I wouldn't say it is completely inappropriate.

Comment: No, it's not inappropriate, it just doesn't feel right. You're right that locutus sum is more grammatical yet clumsier. That's why my real suggestion is colloquium, though I favor forum, too. That said, inquii is used by Cicero, and thus should be accepted as perfectly good Latin.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Unfortunately, _inquii_ spoils the rhythm.

Comment: In Germany, DIXI is a company renting mobile bathrooms. I can't get this association out of my mind.

Comment: @jknappen I should **hope** the chatroom won't go in that direction!!

Answer (score 2):

## Probis pateo

Not a name exactly, but a phrase used to mark places of learning and education. That describes the site and chat well.

Answer (score 2):

## Latin est Gaudium et Utilis

As a tribute to [Wheelock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheelock%27s_Latin).

Answer (score 2):

**Fabulatorium**

a similar idea as locutorium, but with a different verbal root (IMO better fitting to the meaning of "to chat")

Answer (score 2):

Mihi vero placet nomen "**confabulatorium**". *Confabulari* fortasse aptissime convenit anglico *to chat*. Locutorium apud Ducangium testatur (*Locus in Monasteriis in quibus Monachis invicem colloqui licebat, uti et Sanctimonialibus cum in aliis silentium indictum esset.*), sed non est huic vocabulo vis "familiariter colloquendi", quae apertius occurit in *confabulari*.

Answer (score 0):

We should call it 
**Ubi Ubi**

Answer (score 0):

## Sona si Latine loqueris

And a few more characters to reach the minimum